# link is not working at kindle app for iphone 6s?

Tags: css, html, kindle

Hyperlinks are malfunctioning. For instance, if “Appendix F” is hyperlinked to go to exactly that place, the entirety of “Appendix F” in the text is blue and underlined, however, only clicking on the “F” gets one there. Clicking “Appendix” itself, or the entire phrasing, will not. please advise me, how to solve the issue?

Code:

```
test <a href="appc.xhtml#appc">Appendix C</a> code
```

another location.

```
<a id="appc"/>Appendix C
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot self close anchor tags:
`<a id="appc"/>Appendix C`

The reason the entire appendix is blue (and thus a link) is because the browser is auto-closing the tag when you open a new anchor.

You will need to do this:

`<a id="appc">Appendix C</a>`

Comment: Still I'm facing the same issue, the link is working only "C" not "Appendix".

Comment: Could you provide more information? A fiddle/codepen would be useful so that I can see what you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm not understanding your issue. In this code: `<p><a id="appc"></a>Appendix C</p>`  the word Appendix C is not inside the anchor tag and  therefore it is plain text. If you need it to be a link place it inside the anchor tag like so: `<p><a id="appc">Appendix C</a></p>`
Also, you shouldn't make anchor tags without hrefs a div with an id might be more appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: i'm sorry, the browser is support but the kindle app in iphone device is not support. And also the anchor is working partially. For instance "Appendix" or "C", if the content will combine content, link will work only "C".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a slash `/` before the ID-Tag `#appc`

```
test <a href="appc.xhtml/#appc">Appendix C</a> code
```

and change your

> another location.

to  `<a id="appc">Appendix C</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p>The alphabet chart (<a href="appc.xhtml#appc">Appendix C</a>) is a great scaffold</p>
<p id = "appc">Appendix C</p>
```

**(or)**

```
<p>The alphabet chart (<a href="#appc">Appendix C</a>) is a great scaffold</p>
<p><a id="appc"></a>Appendix C</p>
```